# How to make directed graph using Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, directed-graph

I copied this code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("Dash Cytoscape:"),
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'ca', 'label': 'Canada'}}, 
            {'data': {'id': 'on', 'label': 'Ontario'}}, 
            {'data': {'id': 'qc', 'label': 'Quebec'}},
            {'data': {'source': 'ca', 'target': 'on'}}, 
            {'data': {'source': 'ca', 'target': 'qc'}}
        ],
        layout={'name': 'breadthfirst'},
        style={'width': '400px', 'height': '500px'}
    )
])

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

How do I add directed edges in this graph? I have seen examples online and they all add Matplotlib and Plotly to it. I want to change it with minimal changes. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about making your layout (i) directed or to have (ii) edge arrows (or both) :

(i) You can add the parameter 'directed':True to your layout. The new layout would be:

`layout = {'name':'breadthfirst', 'directed':True}`

Other available parameters can be checked on the Cytoscape JavaSript documentation -> https://js.cytoscape.org/

(ii) You can check an example for Edge Arrows on Dash_cytoscape documentation  -> https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/styling

Answer (score 0):

You can add the source-arrow-shape or target-arrow-shape attribute inside the style object as the following example:

```json
{'selector': '#BA',
                'style': {
                    'source-arrow-color': 'red',
                    'source-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                    'line-color': 'red'
                }
            },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).